# Get Webpack Generated File for Karma

Tags: javascript, webpack, karma-runner

When I run `karma start` I get an error like this:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: log4javascript
>     at C:/my/project/test/unit/my-view-model.spec.ts:12469

So, the error is on line 12469.  But that file has about 20 lines it in.

My guess is that webpack is making a bundle for me.  But since it stores it in memory, I can't see it.

**Is there a way to get webpack/karma to output this file to disk?**